# Run-time error 62 Input past end of file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to read the last few bytes of a Microsoft Word file. I am getting the following error on line `MyStr = Input(64, #1)`

> Run-time error 62 Input past end of file

```
Sub Document_Open()
Dim f As Document
Set f = ActiveDocument
MsgBox f.Name
Dim MaxSize, NextChar, MyStr, EndSize
Open f.Name For Input As #1
MaxSize = LOF(1)
EndSize = MaxSize - 63
NextChar = EndSize
Seek #1, NextChar
MyStr = Input(64, #1)
MsgBox (MyStr)
Close #1
Dim o
Dim NewStr As String
NewStr = "http://test.com/?rid=" + MyStr + "&type=doc"
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
o.Open "GET", NewStr, False
o.send
MsgBox (o.responsetext)
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate ("https://en.wikipedia.org/")
IE.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. I modified it and tried to read just 1 byte and it is still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

`Input #` is intended to be used for files what were created with `Write #`, and the result gets "parsed" as it's being read.  You can get more specific information in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264519.aspx).  Word documents are binary files, so that's going to create all kind of problems.  The last 64 bytes of a random .docx file like kind of like this:

```
00 00 08 06 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 20 E2 01 00 77 6F 72 64 2F 66 6F 6E 
74 54 61 62 6C 65 2E 78 6D 6C 50 4B 05 06 00 00 
00 00 0F 00 0F 00 DF 03 00 00 42 E4 01 00 00 00
```

So, you need to open the file `For Binary`.  You can then easily just pull it into a fixed length string with `Get`.

Note that you should also use `FreeFile` instead of hard coded file handles:

```
Dim handle As Integer
handle = FreeFile
Open f.Name For Binary Access Read As handle

Dim last64Bytes As String * 64
Get handle, LOF(handle) - 64, last64Bytes

Debug.Print last64Bytes

Close handle
```